# Why does the asymptotic approximating function for a series sum of a harmonic progression diverge as Bernoulli terms are expanded?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, approximation, bernoulli-numbers

From an earlier [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1948139/is-there-a-series-approximation-in-terms-of-n-for-the-sum-of-the-harmonic-prog), I learned that a closed form approximating expression for the series sum of a harmonic progression can be defined as $$\sum_{k=1}^{f}\frac{1}{1+ak}=\frac{1}{a} (H_{f+ \frac{1}{a}  } - H_{\frac{1}{a}  } )$$ where $H_{f+ \frac{1}{a}}$ and $H_{\frac{1}{a}  }$ are the approximating harmonic numbers and defined as $$H_{\frac{1}{a}  } =  \gamma +log( \frac{1}{a} )+\frac{1}{2 \frac{1}{a}}-\frac{1}{12( \frac{1}{a}) ^{2}}+\frac{1}{120  ( \frac{1}{a})^{4} }+O \big( \frac{1}{( \frac{1}{a})^{5}} \big)$$
and
$$H_{f+ \frac{1}{a}  } =  \gamma +log(f+ \frac{1}{a} )+\frac{1}{2(f+ \frac{1}{a} )}-\frac{1}{12(f+ \frac{1}{a} )^{2} }+\frac{1}{120(f+ \frac{1}{a} )^{4} }+O \big( \frac{1}{(f+ \frac{1}{a} )^{5}} \big)$$

When I numerically test this approximation over a range of positive values for $f$ and $a$, where $a \ll  1$, the results do not tend toward a progressively more accurate solution as the number of Bernoulli terms increase.  Rather, after the first two Bernoulli terms, the solution starts to diverge towards a progressively less accurate result.  I don't understand why this is so.

On a whim, I began to test different numerical constants in the Bernoulli terms (i.e., 12, 120, etc. above) and arrived at a seemingly arbitrary number set (i.e., 12,172,2084) that converges to a result that is two orders of magnitude more accurate (i.e. 0.03% vs 6%).  The expressions I used to approximate the harmonic numbers are;

$$H_{\frac{1}{a}  } =  \gamma +log( \frac{1}{a} )+\frac{1}{2 \frac{1}{a}}-\frac{1}{12( \frac{1}{a}) ^{2}}+\frac{1}{172  ( \frac{1}{a})^{4} }-\frac{1}{2084  ( \frac{1}{a})^{6} }$$
and
$$H_{f+ \frac{1}{a}  } =  \gamma +log(f+ \frac{1}{a} )+\frac{1}{2(f+ \frac{1}{a} )}-\frac{1}{12(f+ \frac{1}{a} )^{2} }+\frac{1}{172(f+ \frac{1}{a} )^{4} }-\frac{1}{2084(f+ \frac{1}{a} )^{6} }$$

Can someone please explain to me (1) why the generally accepted approximating expression produces a low accuracy diverging result and (2) what is the significance of my arbitrary solution that performs much better?

Comment: "... are the harmonic numbers and defined as ...". Those are not the definitions of $H_x$, those are asymptotic approximation, which will be valid only in certain conditions.

Comment: How do I ascertain the "certain conditions"?

Comment: $a$ should be larger than $1$ (as well as $f+1/a$)

Comment: OK.  Then what allows my arbitrary constant selections to perform much better for a << 1?

Comment: Asymptotic series often diverge. The trick is that the larger the argument, the more terms can be included before it starts diverging. Likely your expamsion works well for the range of a being considered, but make a even smaller and the other series will start to do better.

Comment: @eyeballfrog As suggested previously by Giulio,  'a' should be greater than 1.  So I am confused when you suggest making 'a' "smaller to do better.". My 'a' is already substantially below 1.

Comment: It would help to see explicitly some numbers which you tested and on which your series performs much better than the correct one. What is $a$ in your test? If you plot the ratio of Harmonic numbers to a truncated asymptotic series you should see that the best approximation is reached when the coefficients are those of the "standard" (which, indeed, is unique)

Comment: @Giulio  The range of $a$ that I tested was from 350e-9 to 10e-6.  I'm going to put together a couple of charts that show the difference from the perfect series sum.  Via MATLAB, I tested about 10,000 points over the range of 1 <= f <=100 (i.e. 100 steps of $a$ and 100 steps of f.